# nvidia (proprietary) drivers : What are these kernel threads?

Tags: linux-kernel, nvidia, proprietary-drivers, thread, module

Running some 340 driver (with an nvidia.ko module loaded at init time) I moved to a 470 driver and discover half a dozen of kernel threads I failed to find any information about :

- 2 [nv_queue] : What is their purpose & why two occurrences ?
- 2 [nvidia-modeset/] : ditto

launched at init time (possibly when modprobing the nvidia stuff)
Then, launched right after the launch of the X server :

- [irq/27-nvidia] : Most probably the threaded IRQ handler as if I had booted threadirqs (which I did not)
- [nvidia] : good old nvidia.ko threaded ?
- [nv_queue] : ?

Comment: NVIDIA has an open source kernel driver available here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules You could try checking the source code. Not sure why you need to know but whatever ;-)

Comment: Hi! @ArtemS.Tashkinov ! (*birdie* on the nvidia's forum ?). Thanks for the tip, I'll try to dig into that code. I had had a hard time understanding how video was handled on Linux in pre-KMS times particularly as far as the framebuffer was concerned and its sometimes clumsy sharing between the vesafb and the nvidia drivers. Since KMS & 470 driver… I am simply… at lost… and… I just don't like that… ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's my usual nickname everywhere I could claim it (not always of course).

Comment: Similar question from 2019/2020 at https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/what-is-nv-queue-and-why-is-it-the-top-process-on-my-system/75507/15  But still no answers as to what nv_queue actually does (and why it is the most active process).